# Senders Address with Bitcoind in PHP

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, php

I've not been able to figure out why I can't relaiably get the senders address using bitcoind 8.1 on the json API with php.

```
foreach ($bitcoin->listtransactions() as $transaction) {
 if ($transaction['category'] == 'receive') {
  $info['account'] = $transaction['account'];
  $info['address'] = $transaction['address'];
  $info['amount']  = $transaction['amount'];
  $info['confirmations'] = $transaction['confirmations'];
  $info['time'] = $transaction['timereceived'];
  $info['txid'] = $transaction['txid'];

  $txdetails = $bitcoin->getrawtransaction($transaction['txid'],(int)1);
  foreach ($txdetails['vout'] as $vout) {
    if ($vout['value']  $info['amount']) {
      $info['sender'] = $vout['scriptPubKey']['addresses']['0'];
    }
  }
}
```

The result I get is

```
Array
(
    [account] => Pool
    [address] => n3YgVTznqBCTb5ghWwNUoSmn5z37vfg4VK
    [amount] => 2
    [confirmations] => 7
    [time] => 1368107164
    [txid] => 94a25aac9e26b19cbf3c0afd4e7689047e33f9adbea4bbe9d5bd198cdc918717
    [sender] => mvoiUMUyR5QvX1Z2SYBAqT9eK6rjuQGVCF
)
```

But the address I get in the [address] does not receive anything I send back to it.

What am I missing?

Comment: I find it weird that the addresses do not start with a 1 or a 3.

Comment: @StevenRoose These are testnet addresses